# Raspberry hangs at oauth authentification of google calendar api

Tags: javafx, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, raspberry-pi3, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a javaFX app, which uses the google calendar api. I tested it on two Windows PC's and erverything is working fine. The code from google opens the browser where I can authentificate me, than it creates a token und load the calendar data. Unfortunately my target plattform is the Raspberry Pi 3 and there it freezes the system when calling the oauth authentification.

For testing, I extracted just the code from google where the authentification happens and bundled it as a seperated jar. Running this jar on the raspy do not cause any problems, it opens the browser and let me authentificate. But capsuled in the rest of my code, it freezes, although I do nothing more than creating an object and call the getCredentials method, excactly the same thing I did in the extracted Jar. 
So I thought, maybe it's caused by javaFX, so I bundled the api google code as javaFX Jar, but it runs perfectly on the raspy. 
So I am out of ideas and want to ask, if someone had run into same kind of problems.

Hope someone can help me
Thanks a lot.

Googles API code I just copied:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "test";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    try {
        InputStream in = GoogleCalendar.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Event> getCalendarData(int maxResults) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Events events = service.events().list("primary")
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)
            .setTimeMin(now)
            .setOrderBy("startTime")
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .execute();
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    return items;
}
```

And this is from where I call the API code:

```
    public void update() {
    vbox_main.getChildren().clear();
    label_head.setText(gCalObj.getName() + "'s Google Calender");
    label_head_date.setText(getActualDate());
    GoogleCalendar gCal = new GoogleCalendar();
    try {
        List<Event> items = gCal.getCalendarData(gCalObj.getMaxResult());
        if(items != null) {
            System.out.println("size: " + items.size());
            if (items.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Upcoming events");
                for (Event event : items) {
                    DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                    if (start == null) {
                        start = event.getStart().getDate();
                    }
                    //System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
                    createDateRow(event.getSummary(), start);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("no data arrived");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output when freezing on Raspberry Pi 3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAiOS.png)

Comment: When you say you bundle the Google code as Java/JavaFX jar, how did you run it on your Pi? As a Java or as a JavaFX application? When it runs, it opens the browser? A native browser? Can you post your Java and JavaFX versions?

Comment: Thanks for your response. On my PC I'm using the java version 1.8.0_144 and than the corresponding javafx version i suppose. I'm not quite sure how to find out about the exact version, but I didn't install anything extra. 
On the raspy however I installed the overlay "OpenJFX builds for Linux ARMv6 hard float" from https://chriswhocodes.com/ to be able to run javafx there.
On the Pi I run the javafx jar with this command: java -Djavafx.platform=gtk2 -jar FXfile.jar

Comment: And what about the "native" browser? On your Pi, do you run from command line or from the GUI? Do you use WebView?

Comment: The Google api takes care of opening the browser. I looked for the code which opens it in the dependencies but didn't found it. But I didnt look that hard, because the api code for itself is working fine. On the Pi it opens Chromium